# Oracle missing keyword

Tags: oracle

SQL like this:

```
CREATE VIEW UOS_VU_COURSE_MODULES
SELECT MODULE.MODULE_TITLE, STAFF.FIRST_NAME, STAFF.LAST_NAME, MODULE.SEMESTER, MODULE.CREDIT
FROM STAFF, MODULE
WHERE MODULE.COODINATOR_ID =STAFF.STAFF_ID AND COURSE.COURSE_ID=INFU101 AND
COURSE.COURSE_ID=MGTU17
ORDER BY MODULE.MODULE_TITLE
```

It appears ORA-00905: missing keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Missing `AS` keyword:

```
CREATE VIEW UOS_VU_COURSE_MODULES
AS
SELECT 
    MODULE.MODULE_TITLE, STAFF.FIRST_NAME, STAFF.LAST_NAME, 
    MODULE.SEMESTER, MODULE.CREDIT
FROM 
    STAFF, MODULE
WHERE 
    MODULE.COODINATOR_ID = STAFF.STAFF_ID AND COURSE.COURSE_ID = INFU101 AND
    COURSE.COURSE_ID = MGTU17
ORDER BY MODULE.MODULE_TITLE
```

Ref.: [CREATE VIEW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code there.

1. The AS is required, of course.
2. That upper case code style is really hard to read, which is why motorway road signs do not use it any more.
3. The join style is outdated and you ought to be using the ANSI SQL method.
4. You have two predicates on course.course_id that look like they should be literals, but unfortunately if they are then they contradict each other.

Anyway, you ought to have something that looks more supportable:

```
create view
  uos_vu_course_modules
as
select
  module.module_title,
  staff.first_name   ,
  staff.last_name    ,
  module.semester    ,
  module.credit
from
  staff join
  module on (module.coodinator_id = staff.staff_id)
where
  course.course_id = 'INFU101' and
  course.course_id = 'MGTU17'
order by
  module.module_title;
```

Perhaps the WHERE clause should be

```
  course.course_id = 'INFU101' or
  course.course_id = 'MGTU17'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `AS` after view name:

```
create view UOS_VU_COURSE_MODULES AS
```